# Applescript file search using data from a spreadsheet

Tags: search, csv, applescript, filenames

I am currently using this Applescript I found that searches for a file name and returns the file path in a text doc. This works fine for finding 1 or 2 files, but I would like to find 500 files that are spread over hundreds of folders. My ideal script would use data from an excel spreadsheet or csv, perform a search, find the file and make a copy of it in a designated folder on my desktop. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the script I found:

```
tell application "System Events"
    activate
    set thePattern to text returned of (display dialog "Search for" default answer "")
    end tell
    if thePattern = "" then return
   try
    set foundFiles to do shell script "mdfind -name " & quoted form of thePattern & " |         /usr/bin/egrep -i " & quoted form of thePattern & "[^/]*/?$ | /usr/bin/grep -vi " & quoted     form of thePattern & ".*" & quoted form of thePattern
on error
    set foundFiles to "Nothing Returned"
end try
if foundFiles = "" then set foundFiles to "Nothing Returned"

tell application "TextEdit"    
activate
delay 0.5
try
    set theDoc to document 1
    get text of theDoc
    if result is not "" then
        make new document
        set theDoc to result
    end if
on error
    make new document
    set theDoc to result
end try
set text of theDoc to foundFiles
end tell
```

Comment: What would the excel spreadsheet or csv contain, file names?

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the data from the text file, then turn it into a return or linefeed delimited list and do a repeat over the items of this list. Then turn each item (which is actually a line) into e.g. a tab delimited list and again do a (nested) repeat loop over the items of this list. If you know that e.g. item 3 is the file path, you can set a variable to item 3 of the line as text and use this variable in your shell script.

I think you need to show that you understand the concept of repeat loops by posting your own attempt of implementing this. If you do, I'll be happy to come back and help you with the next step.

Kind regards,

Mark